# All lines of code not executing in python

Tags: python

why is only part of my code running in python?
I tried the same code in IDLE and SUBLIMETEXT and it only runs the first two lines and that is it.
as shown below

```
print("hello")
first = input("what is your firstname? ")
print("thanks")
surname = input("what is your surname? ")
```

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: Are you providing the input?

Comment: Provide the error(if exist) , a minimal reproduction example

Comment: hello what is first name @hadi k

Comment: hello what is your name this is the output, it should more

Comment: It's waiting for you to type a first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. You may be confused with 2 things:

1. The `input()` function pauses the execution until you will finish entering something (or nothing) and pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
2. After your last command, when you entered required info (your surname) and pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, there is no other command to print something.
   So your program will finish silently, not using the last entered info (your surname).

Comment: ok thanks so what do I do? i am new just learning? I suspected it had to do with the input function though

Comment: so how do i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It's waiting for the `raw_input` to run- raw_input is a function that waits for user input.

Try typing something in and pressing enter when the program asks What is your firstname?- the rest of the program will run.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in CodeSculptor and it worked OK:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_1ZWADnYLXt_0.py

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted a little modified version of your program:

```
print("hello")
first = input("what is your firstname? ")
surname = input("what is your surname? ")
print("thanks", first, surname)
```

The difference is in swapping the last 2 lines and adding the variables `first` and `surname` to the `print()` function (to display the entered info, i.e. the first name and the surname).

The output from doing it in the Python IDLE (after File→New, copy/paste the code into the new empty window, pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, entering the name `myprogram` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>; then — of course — entering names (`John` and `Doe):`

```
====== RESTART: C:/Program Files/Python36/Lib/idlelib/myprogram.py ======
hello
what is your firstname? John
what is your surname? Doe
thanks John Doe
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it as you said but it did not run it gave me response hello what is your first name

Comment: In which environment do you work? In Python IDLE? In PyCharm? Or in some on-line testing tool? You have to find WHERE to write answer to you questions ("what is your firstname? " and "what is your surname? "), and write them with pressing Enter at the end.

Comment: If you use an on-line service, you have to fill answers **in advance**, before you launch your code. Maybe there is some button with text as "open input box* - you have to click it to obtain the opportunity to write (**in advance**) required data (first name and surname) of your program.

Comment: i am working with sublime text I also tried with idle it only gives the answer to the first line.

Comment: In the IDLE you have to do this from the top menu: File→New File. Then to the empty file copy/paste my code. The press F5. You obtain the pop-up window "Source Must Be Saved. OK to Save?". Click on OK and to the next pop-up window write the name for your program, e.g. `myprogram` and press Enter (or click to "Save" button). Immediately after this your program start running and you may enter first an last names. I am going to append the output of it to my answer.

Comment: wooooooow thanks so much now i get what its been talking about all day you need to press enter and enter again.. jeez I am gratefull, been here 8 hours could not go forward

Comment: went back to write the code in sublime text it did not work but it works perfectly in IDLE

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text you need to install the [SublimeREPL](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin.

Without it your program *isn't able to accept user's input,* so after your second command

```
first = input("what is your firstname? ")
```

it displays

> ```
> hello
> what is your firstname?
> ```

and waits for user input, but is *unable to continue with the next one* — there is *no point in writing anything (your first name) to the prompt.* (It will be displayed but your program will not accept it.)

---

After installing the [SublimeREPL](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin, select

Tools → SublimeREPL → Python → Python-RUN current file.

---

*Note:* The “REPL” abbreviation means *“Read-Evaluate-Print Loop”.*

Answer (score -1):

The code seems to be fine. Shouldn't be a problem in execution. It will take your first name as input, once you type that in and hit Enter, it will ask you for the surname.

TRY ADDING SEMICOLON AT THE END OF EACH LINE. 
or maybe just type all of it in one line. For example:

```
 print("Hello");  first = input("your first name"); print("HELLO 2");  second = input("your last name")
```

Comment: Its not the standard python syntax I agree. But it could be used to test if the problem is with the code or the syntax of the code. I just executed this code on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: thanks for your response but it still did not work it only runs the first part of the code, i think it has to do with the input function I am just 2 weeks learning so this is why i am going through this

Comment: Here is how the code will execute:
Step 1. print("HELLO")
- Till will print Hello on console
Step 2. first = Input("first name")
- This will REQUIRE you to TYPE something and HIT ENTER

after this the rest of the code will start to run.